# How can we pass list of spotcolor values in PDFLib set-graphics-option?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdflib, pantone, spotcolor

I have integrated **PDFLib** library in the c#.net code and I have a requirement to set multiple **spotcolor** values in **set-graphics-option** method.

[image]

I tried the below code but it didn't work... Appreciate your help to fix this.

```c
 1. optlist = "fillcolor={spotcolor {PANTONE 281 U} 1}, {spotcolor {PANTONE 15-14 C} 1}"
 2. optlist = "fillcolor={spotcolor {PANTONE 281 U} 1} {spotcolor {PANTONE 15-14 C} 1}"
 3. optlist = "fillcolor={[{spotcolor {PANTONE 281 U} 1}][{spotcolor {PANTONE 15-14 C} 1}]}"
```

Comment: I guess this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58416267/pdflib-set-graphics-option-how-to-pass-list-of-colors-in-fillcolor-option

Answer (score 0):

It's **not** possible. You can only have a single color for stroke or fill at the same time.

What should be the benefit of multiple values?